# Launching a specific version of Excel using xlwings

Tags: excel, xlwings

I have Excel 2003 and 365 installed on my  Windows 10 computer.  Using python and xlwings I wish to open a blank Excel 365 workbook along the lines wb = xw.Book().  Can someone please advise me if this is possible and if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't target a specific installation of Excel with xlwings if it isn't open yet. The only thing that I remember should work is to "repair" the Office installation you want to use with xlwings when doing `xlwings.App()`. Whatever installation you install or repair last should be the default installation that xlwings uses. This should only be an issue if Excel is not running yet.