# Saving xlwings workbook still problematic

Tags: python-3.x, excel, path, save, xlwings

Using xlwings I want to save an Excel workbook with a different name in a different directory.  Numerous attempts, including advice offered in this forum, have not worked.

```
import xlwings as xw
path1 = 'mine/path1/'
path2 = 'mine/path2/'

app = xw.App()  # including this line does not help
wb = xw.Book(path1 + 'XXX.xlsx')
wb.save() #  this works as expected
wb.save(path1 + 'YYY.xlsx')  # this doesn't work
wb.save(path2 + 'YYY.xlsx')  # neither does this
```

Error message running the last line (second last commented out):

C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\valenv\python.exe C:/Users/Owner/PycharmProjects/FIIG/stuff.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Owner\PycharmProjects\FIIG\stuff.py", line 32, in 
wb.save(path5 + 'XXX.xlsx')

File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\valenv\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 740, in save
self.impl.save(path)

File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\valenv\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py", line 552, in save
self.xl.SaveAs(os.path.realpath(path), FileFormat=file_format)

File "C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\valenv\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py", line 66, in **call**
v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py", line 46793, in SaveAs  return self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(3174, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this. This works for me with xlwings 0.23.1:

```py
import xlwings as xw

path1 = 'C:/Users/felix/Desktop/'

wb = xw.Book(path1 + 'Book1.xlsx')
wb.save(path1 + 'YYY.xlsx')
```

Comment: I tried that and got exactly the same message.  Opening RIO.csv didn't make any difference.    I have xlwings32-0.23.1.dll and xlwings64-0.23.1.dll installed in my Conda distribution.  Running PyCharm Pro on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine.

Comment: @ValendarTurner Do you mind opening an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Serendipity fixed the problem.  The PyCharm Path was not updated over the Community version.  However although the code now works, when I open the saved xlsx file, it is an empty work-sheet which flashes data as I close it.  Removing app=xw.App() cures this behaviour and the file opens as expected.  The first line of code opens an instance of MS 365 Excel while removing it opens Excel 2003.  I wonder if this is related to my yet unanswered question at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67068419/launching-a-specific-version-of-excel-using-xlwings

Comment: I just started running into the same problem, yet my scripts have been working fine for weeks. Was there an update?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with xlwings before and the fix I came to was to shorten the length of the filename I was saving.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33409096)